# Magento 2: How to show multiple discount coupon code separately in backend while creating order (order totals)

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, backend, discount

> I using Magento 2.4.2. In the front end, After applying the
> multiple discount coupon, It will show you
> both coupon code separately which is fine, as shown in the below
> screenshot,

[image: Screenshot1]

> In the backend, When creating the new order and after applying the
> discount coupon code it will show you the mixed discount, as shown in
> the below screenshot,

[image: Screenshot2]

> **So the question is how can I show the discount coupon code separately with the amount in the backend(as shown in frontend) while creating an order? but it's not showing separately.**

> etc/sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="custom_coupon_amount" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Coupon" sort_order="420"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Coupon.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;

class Coupon extends AbstractTotal
{
    const DISCOUNT_CODE = 'custom_coupon_amount';


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * Coupon constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * Collect discount
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param Total $total
     */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

        $this->setCouponsValues();
    }

    /**
     * Assign discount amount
     *
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @param Total $total
     *
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(Quote $quote, Total $total)
    {
        return [
            'code' => self::DISCOUNT_CODE,
            'title' => __('CustomCoupon'),
            'value' => $this->session->getCouponAmount()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Set coupons values into session
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCouponsValues()
    {
        $this->session->setCouponAmount($this->helper->getCouponsWithAmount());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Helper getCouponsWithAmount()

```
/**
     * Return amount of discount for each rule
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCouponsWithAmount()
    {
        $totalCustomAmount = [];
        foreach ($this->customAmount as $couponCode => $couponAmount) {
            $totalCustomAmount[] = [
                'custom_coupon_code'   => $this->getCodeDescription($couponCode),
                'custom_coupon_amount' =>
                    '-' .$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->format($couponAmount, [], false)
            ];
        }
        return $totalCustomAmount;
    }
```

**Please let me know if anyone has any ideas or at least tell me which are the files I need to look at in vendor.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found an solution by overriding the phtml file,

```
Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals/default.phtml
```

> For this file, you will need to override the block file,

```
Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Totals/DefaultTotals.php
Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Totals/Discount.php
```

> DefaultTotals.php

```
class DefaultTotals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals\DefaultTotals
{
    /**
     * Template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_module::order/create/totals/default.phtml';
}
```

> Discount.php

```
class Discount extends \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals\DefaultTotals
{
   
}
```

**Hope it helps.**